# Energy release on impact

Tags: energy, collision

I was watching this video from a video game showing a space ship travelling towards a planet at 22% the speed of light. The ship system pulls the ship out of this "quantum travel" just in time to avoid a collision.

This made me curious; what would happen if the system was to malfunction and the ship collides with the planet? How much energy would actually be released?

I calculated it to be equivalent to roughly 800,000 Hiroshima bombs (for a 22 ton ship). Is this really accurate?

I just got really curious and would love an answer to this. Thanks.

EDIT: I first calculated the kinetic energy of the ship `K = (1/2)mv^2` -> `K = (1/2) * 22000 * 66000000^2` -> `K ~ 48,000,000,000,000,000,000 Joules

The Hiroshima bomb released 63 TJ so 48*10^18 / 63*10^12 ~ 760,000

Comment: Hi. Can you include in your question how you arrived at '800,000 Hiroshima bombs'? It would make the question more interesting.

Comment: Relativistic KE is approximately 5x10^19 Joules. 22 metric tons at 0.22c. I don't know the energy of the Hiroshima bomb.

Comment: @gert Added in post

Comment: @PeterR Yeah, I got it to approx 4.8x10^19. The Hiroshima bomb was 63 TJ.

Comment: @Gert, no input?

Comment: @Chris: maybe later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've underestimated the effect, although your math is correct as far as it goes.

At 22% of c, relativistic effects do rear their ugly heads, and the proper equation is $$ KE = \frac{\frac{mv^2}{2}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} = 7.6\times10^{19}\text{ J}$$ Divide by $63\times10^{12}$ and the ratio is 1,200,000 (1.2 million).

And yes, this is an unreasonably large amount of energy. If you turn it around, it demonstrates just how hard it is to create a drive which will accelerate a ship to relativistic speeds in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for input. Sometimes its just fun to try and contemplate on these things. I wonder though in what fashion this energy would be released (I dont imagine fireballs and mushroom clouds) and what the aftermath would me. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The formula that WhatRoughBeast uses is not correct. It should be
$$KE = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2}} - 1\right) mc^2 = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-0.22^2}} - 1\right) (22,000)(3\cdot10^8)^2 = 5\cdot10^{19} J$$
Your calculation wasn't far off since relativistic effects aren't very large at 22% of the speed of light, so $KE = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$ is still pretty close to correct.